# cakePHP 3.10 - When NOT using "default" db connection... Controllers cannot find Flash! cakePHP is skipping AppController->initialize()

Tags: cakephp, components, cakephp-3.0, require-once

When working with a "default" db connection the following code works great:

```
    function index()
    {
        $this->Flash->success("OK???????");
```

HOWEVER when working with a db connection other than "default" (SecondaryPersons)... Things begin to die horribly:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $this->Flash->error("DOES NOT WORK!");
```

ERRORS:
Notice: Notice (1024): Undefined property: SecondaryPersonsController::$Flash ...

I've traced both and found the following:

```
[default db]
    Application::bootstrap()
    AppController::initialize()
    SecondaryPersonsController::index()

[SecondaryPersons]
    Application::bootstrap()
    
    SecondaryPersonsController::index()
```

WHAT? There is no call to AppController::initialize() which is of course where all of the

```
loadComponent()
require_once()
```

is located!

Is there some reason I would need to duplicate this code for the Secondary DBs in each controller?

Comment: Does your `SecondaryPersonsController` have an `initialize` function? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: @GregSchmidt ````$this->loadModel( 'LocalShooterControls' );
        $this->loadModel( 'LocalShooterMailLists' );
        $this->loadModel( 'LocalShooterAffiliations' );````  I see I forgot the very important parent::initialize() !!!!

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thank you for the suggestion.  I would gladly give thumbs up on your suggestion...